# How to avoid Seaborn lineplot to continue a line with nan data

Tags: python, seaborn

I am working with a dataset to create lineplots of several sensors. Some of the sensors datasets miss a number of days of data, which is shown in the dataset as a nan. When plotting the data in seaborn.lineplot the gap with nan values is interpolated as a straight line.

How can I not plot anything rather than have the straight line?

Comment: Note that, to be acceptable, your question needs reproducible code and test data.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to split the sections and plot them as separate traces. Then give them all the same color.